# toolbar width without menu button

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I've created application with menu and toolbar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_menu_coord_layout_included"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />


    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_menu"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_menu_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The toolbar (the **app_bar_menu_coord_layout_included** above):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_menu_coord_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:tag="app_bar_menu_coord_layout"
    tools:context="com.magnifi.pennantrace.MenuActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/relativelayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <!--first-->
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar_div_rank"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="4th Place"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/guidelineToolbarV1"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/guidelineToolbarH1"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                ...

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now I wanted to adjust text sizes of toolbar elements depending on screen size. What I do is take toolbar width as 100% and set the rest of textview's text sizes to fit the desired rectangle (for example 6% of width and 100% of height).

But it seems like its not working properly.
I've tested on screen size 320 height and 480 width:

[image: example]

As you see on the picture, first of all the width of it is 480, and as I noticed the text adjustment doesn't work, take a look on the last text 37M, it should have fitted into one line. What I think is that the menu button (the red rectangle in image) is taking some place. What would be the best way to identify actual width of toolbar without the menu button?

**EDIT 1:**
I've tried adding to the **app_bar_menu_coord_layout_included** this:

> android:layout_marginLeft="-64dp"

And here is the result of correct text size adjustment. But I don't want to get rid of the menu button. Instead I want to get correct size of toolbar without menu button.

[image: example 2]

Answer (score 0):

**Android gave us components to make ease implementing components. Not for giving hours to customise it. Why don't you make an custom toolbar instead of wasting hours in managing default toolbar.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    style="@style/styleToolbar">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_back"
            style="@style/styleToolbarIcon"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_back" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/headerTitle"
            style="@style/styleToolbarText"
            android:text="@string/app_name" />

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

some styles to be put in res>values>styles.xml.

```
<style name="styleToolbar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">?attr/actionBarSize</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
    <item name="theme">@style/MyToolbarTheme</item>
    <item name="contentInsetEnd">0dp</item>
    <item name="contentInsetLeft">0dp</item>
    <item name="contentInsetRight">0dp</item>
    <item name="contentInsetStart">0dp</item>
    <item name="contentInsetStartWithNavigation">0dp</item>
</style>

<style name="MyToolbarTheme">
    <!-- Used to tint the back arrow, menu and spinner arrow -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#FFF</item>
</style>

<style name="styleToolbarIcon">
    <item name="android:layout_width">?attr/actionBarSize</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:contentDescription">@string/app_name</item>
    <item name="android:padding">@dimen/toolbar_icon_padding</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>

<style name="styleToolbarText">
    <item name="android:layout_width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">left|center_vertical</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#252525</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:scrollHorizontally">true</item>
</style>
```

You should customize the toolbar layout as per your need. So you will have all controls on its size.